# How do I search some files for cases when a certain function is called with its optional arguments?

Tags: javascript, regex, search, grep

I want to search a directory of files to find all cases where the commonly used `dojo.map` function is called with its optional fourth parameter.

**I want to find things like**

```
map(an_array, a_function_by_name, x, fourth_arg);
```

or with the inline function too:

```
map(an_array, function(item, i, arr){
    //anything
}, x, fourth_arg);
```

**I don't want to find cases without the fourth, optional, argument.** This function is very common in the code base and I would have to wade through hundreds of false positives to find the cases I really want

```
//this function also can be called with just 2 or 3 parameters
//(the second parameter can still be inline or not)

map(an_array, a_function);
map(an_array, a_function, x);
```

I initially considered grep-ing for something like `map([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)` but I don't think this is sufficient since the second argument is a function, meaning it not only can span multiple lines but can also contain arbitrary Javascript code inside.

---

**What is the most effective way to find all cases when the function is called with all four arguments?** I'm on a Linux machine and don't mind installing a small tool for this if that happens to be the simplest solution.

Comment: If you've really got all sorts of variations in the invocations, there's no way to do this short of actually parsing the files with a JavaScript parser.  Because it's JavaScript of course, even *that* is going to be hard, since determining which function calls you identify syntactically are the ones you're actually worried about is itself quite hard.

Comment: @Pointy: I know its not trivial, thats why Im asking it here :) But I'm not sure you need a full Javascript parser, since I already know the code is well formed - matching opening and closing braces and parens might be enough to put bounds on the functions and arguments

Comment: Well maybe; it depends on your code. All it takes is a quoted string with unmatched "(" or "{" characters, for example, to mess up something simple. And a regex is not going to be very good for handling parenthesis nesting.

Comment: There is no way doing that with regular expressions. Once you have the potential for nested token pairs (as in '{' n '}' or '(' and ')') regular expressions are out of the question.

Comment: @FK82: I'm perfectly fine with any solution here. You can use cheater Perl regexes if you want

Comment: @missingno: Sorry, would love to help, but I can't. Try a bounty. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one high-level approach:

1. Parse the JavaScript into an AST.  If you use a tool like [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/), [there is a JavaScript grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g) that you can employ to generate your tree.
2. Walk through the AST, finding the function calls that use the identifier `map`, and inspect how many arguments are passed to the call.

This of course has its limitations:

1. It will not tell you whether the Dojo `map` function is what is being called, only that a function reference named `map` is used.
2. It will not find cases where `map` is called through "dynamic binding."  In other words, although this is a call to `map`, it would not be found: `window['map'](foo, bar, baz, bah);`.

Perhaps this is sufficient for your needs despite these restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You could alter the dojo.map function and add some lines which will retrive to you the arguments.caller this would be the function which called map. If you also verify inside map function how many parameters does it have using `arguments[]` you could `console.log(arguments.caller)` just when `arguments[0] && arguments[0]`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this has the benefit of being able to find even the les obvious calls, like using call, apply or an alias, having it will only work if the function gets called is a big negative for me. Since this is library code that has lots of browser-specific branching paths a static solution is progably better.

Answer (score 0):

*No idea if this would work; not tested, just shooting from my hip right before leaving work!* :-)

Could you (temporarily) remove the fourth parameter from the function signature, then use a Javascript compiler across the directory to see what breaks?

Comment: Sadly, this is not useful. 1) Javascript allows you to pass any number of parameters to functions, so removing one wouldn't necessarily make things break 2) That argument is optional 3) I don't know where are the calls using all 4 parameters. That is the point of the question...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm mistaking here, I'm not too good using RegExes myself. Haven't tested either, just saying what comes to my mind. ;)

However, have you considered making the RegEx "ungreedy" like the following?

```
map(.*?,(.*?|function\([^)]\{.*?\}),.*?,.*?)
```

You may want to check the correct syntax for this... but AFAIK, making the RegEx "ungreedy" should cause it to get as much as possible for the repeating characters that matches. That of course also means, that for example parameters 1 or 3 could contain an additional comma, if the parameter count goes up to 5 or more, which is rather unlikely in this case.

Maybe this is a work-around for the nesting problem? Maybe I reversed it and it's actually called "greedy"..? Has been a while since I've worked with RegExes.

Any expert's help on this greatly appreciated so I can learn something myself, too! ;D

Comment: The problem is that regexes don't guarantee that the `{}` are matching. This means that the pattern can erroneously match a `}` inside the function.